# Can't CONCAT a column and another string in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

I have a PostgreSQL table with a text field with a default value of an empty string ('') that will be a list of tags. I am trying to update that field by appending a string using CONCAT, but it is not working. This is my SQL:

```
UPDATE pins SET tags = concat(tags, :tagString) WHERE id = :id
```

`$tagString` would look something like this: `[5378]`

Similar queries have worked like this:

```
UPDATE pins SET tags = :tagString WHERE id = :id
```

It seems that the problem is the `concat` function. What is wrong?

Comment: What is "not working"? What result are you getting with the current query?

Comment: The first query will not cause any change in the tags column. The second query will successfully set tags = :tagString. So I narrowed the problem to the concat function not working.

Comment: Have you tried with the concatenation operator `||`? Like: `tags || :tagString`